# Removal of @synthesize

Tags: objective-c, synthesize

New to Obj-C; enrolled in a class to teach myself. I have the following working code for an exercise, but now must remove the @synthesize and modify the program to handle the new names given to the instance variables by the compiler. Tried a multitude of things; always get compiler errors due to not knowing how @synthesize fully implements and what removing it means. Thanks for any explanation, SO.

main.m

```
#import "Fraction.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        Fraction *aFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];

        [aFraction setTo: 100 over: 200];
        [aFraction print];

        [aFraction setTo: 1 over: 3];
        [aFraction print];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Fraction.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Fraction : NSObject

@property int numerator, denominator;

-(void)     print;
-(void)     setTo: (int) n over: (int) d;
-(double)   convertToNum;

@end
```

Fraction.m

```
#import "Fraction.h"

@implementation Fraction

@synthesize numerator, denominator;

-(void) print {
    NSLog(@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}

-(double) convertToNum {
    if (denominator != 0) return (double) numerator / denominator;
    else return NAN;
}

-(void) setTo: (int) n over: (int) d {
    numerator = n;
    denominator = d;
}
@end
```

Comment: This is not `Fraction.m` :) -- Removing `@synthesize propertyName` implicitly is like `@synthesize propertyName = _propertyName`, i.e. the ivars are prefixed with an underscore.

Comment: If you are following a tutorial or taking a class that is showing you to use `@synthesize` or the explicit creation of ivars for your properties, find a newer, better tutorial or class.

Comment: I learned through a previous SO question that this book and class is entirely antiquated. That said, can anyone explain in a way I'd understand how this would work? Even though it is not the correct way, I don't understand how it's incorrect without knowing why it's incorrect.

Comment: Update your question with Fraction.m. You posted main.m twice by mistake.

Comment: Done, @rmaddy. Sorry about that confusion.

Comment: Do as @fluidsonic stated in the first comment. Remove the `@synthesize` line and note that the synthesized ivars will have a same name as the property but with a leading underscore. But you should reference the properties directly using `self.somePropertyName` instead of accessing the ivar.

Comment: Thank you. I simply did not understand until now. Much appreciated!